# How to iterate over an array returned by a function in Java

Tags: java, arrays, function, for-loop, iteration

What's the best way to iterate over an array returned by a function?

Example:

```
for (String s : collectMyStrings()){
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

Is collectMyStrings() called in each iteration, or does Java only call it once, and use the returned array for all iterations of the for loop?

Comment: You could answer your own question by just trying it!

Comment: Yes, but I like to have it documented, if others try google, like i did

Comment: if you were really concerned you could always save it as a variable and then loop over the variable. But I think it will only call it once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be called only once, and an iterator for the returned array will be created (implicitly).

Comment: For arrays, the compiler transforms the for-each loop into an ordinary for loop with an index variable. Only for-each loops on `Iterable` objects are transformed to the Iterator-based loop.

Comment: Just to add a bit more context to this.  I believe that you can't/shouldn't modify what is being iterated over.  So it would make sense for the compiler to cache off the returned iterable.

Answer (score 2):

For arrays, the for-each loop is transformed by the Java compiler into an ordinary for loop with an index variable. That means that your code snippet is roughly equivalent to the this:

```
String[] strings = collectMyStrings();
int length = strings.length;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    String s = strings[i];
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

So, as you can see, the method is called only once. Even the length property of the array is read only once.

Answer (score 0):

The method `collectMyStrings()` is only called once to get the array/collection to iterate over.